# is background audio playing enabled in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, background

I was able to play the audio in background of the application in iPhone. However I would like to know if there is any service that enables the playback of audio after the user exits the application?
I know that SDK 4.0 promises multitasking and background processes of the application. But i would like to know if this is enabled for audio playback in the earlier versions?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a feature Apple has reserved for its own apps in all versions of iPhone OS prior to version 4.0.